# Wrong customer reset password link (admin link instead of front)

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with customer receiving a wrong reset password link, in the reset password email, it's an admin link.

```
https://mydoamin.com/admin/customer/account/createPassword/?token=
```

It occurred when the customer store is 0 (admin)
Magento 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

check this page, its a magento issue i guess

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35487

Comment: no, it's not the same error, in my case it occurred cause the store id is 0 (admin)